# No se encontró el tipo 'Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

Intento programa un estilo desde el app.xaml de VisualStudio, al momento de usar el estilo `SystemDropShadowChrome` me arroja el siguiente error.

> No se encontró el tipo 'Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome'. Compruebe que no falte una referencia a un ensamblado y que se han copilado todos los ensamblados a los que se hace referencia

Comment: El error es suficientemente descriptivo. Parece que falta una referencia, pero sin ver código es imposible decirte más.

Comment: estoy utilizando esta referencia pero nada `    xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2"`